# Error using substr

Tags: c++, string

I am trying to write a function that removes whitespace from beginning and end of string and I keep getting the error

```
error C3867: 'std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>::length': function call missing argument list;
use '&std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>::length' to create a pointer to member"
```

Here's my source code

```
string trim(string str)
{
    int i = 0;
    for (char c : str)
    {
        if (!isspace(c))
            break;
        i++;
    }

    string trimmed = str.substr(i, (str.length-i));

    i = 0;
    for (char c : str)
    {
        if (isspace(c))
            break;
        i++;
    }

    trimmed = trimmed.substr(0, i);
    return trimmed;
}
```

What is wrong?

Comment: I'd say the error message is pretty clear. `length` is missing the argument list, pointing toward the fact that it's a function.

Comment: I agree with chris. @Celeritas Maybe you could post the *full* error message as a code block to make it easier to find this via Google!?

Comment: @Celeritas Maybe what you posted already is the full error message? I'm not sure at the moment.

Comment: It is full error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
string trimmed = str.substr(i, (str.length-i));
```

Use

```
string trimmed = str.substr(i, (str.length()-i));
```

[`length()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/length/) it is a function, not a member. This is handled differently in other languages.

Note that [`size()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/size/) is a synonym of `length()`.

Comment: @chris Just as you commented, I removed this distinction again. Thanks !